# How to add long lists in thesis

Tags: thesis, bioinformatics

We performed some bioinformatic work during thesis. Output of these analysis are more than 10 tables with 2000 rows each. We cannot add these in the printed version of the thesis, so we thought about:

- link to the online version, since paper containing this data was published.
- give a CD-ROM with the thesis, but for me this physical format is obsolete.

Maybe you have a better alternative or agree with the first one like me.

Comment: For online version, you may want to drop it into a well-known [data repository](http://www.nature.com/sdata/data-policies/repositories) or even [the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/help/datasets). (Please don't just put the online version on your group website, unless you intend to permanently maintain a stable URL and provide archival storage of the information.)

Comment: @Willie Wong, do you think giving the link to the journal where paper was published is not adequate? I mean direct link to data.

Comment: Can you please clarify: 1) What sort of thesis is this; in particular, is it a published thesis? 2) Who is *we?*

Comment: It is not clear to me what you meant by "Paper containing this data was published". Do you mean that the data is included in a (long) paper published somewhere? Do you mean that the data is included as online supplementary information for a paper somewhere? Or do you mean simply that a paper based on that data is published somewhere? In the first two cases then yes, you can just link to the published version. But in case two depending how your journal handles supplementary information it may still be a good idea to publish the data elsewhere in addition.

Comment: @Willie Wong, the data was included as online supplementary information for a paper.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, thesis is organized by chapters, but chapter content was published as papers, added at the end of the thesis as annexes. Since papers have the link to supplementary data (the long tables), I think I will rely on these links indicating it at the corresponding chapter.

Comment: Welcome to the internet! There are tons of places when you can share data. You can use pastebin to paste it as text, or github, or even a public link to your dropbox account!

Comment: If you have published your data/papers already in a journal, be a bit careful with who actually holds the rights to these. Most journals allow you to reuse things for your thesis, but for some you have to request this. They might be a bit more picky if you decide to make your data publicly available online though - so just linking to your own paper is probably the safer alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Output of these analysis are more than 10 tables with 2000 rows each. We cannot add these in the printed version of the thesis ...

Even if you could (say for instance you hate trees and you don't pay for your thesis), do you think anybody would want to have that kind of data in physical format?

Both alternatives are valid, but as you said optical media is becoming more and more obsolete. If you ***really*** want to provide the data in a physical form, you can distribute it as a usb-stick. As the capacity of sticks increase, smaller drives become dirt cheap. You should be able to get 1GB, 2GB or even 4GB for relatively small price in hundreds.

The other option, online availability, is the better alternative in general. However the maintenance of data is important as others have mentioned. Both in terms of availability and proper cataloging try to use well known and established repositories.

What I don't understand however, is why you feel the need to "republish" findings, if you have already deposited this data together with a prior publication. Just refer to the data as *"Table/Supplementary Info X from Paper Y"*

Comment: It's also possible that physical media could be a requirement of the university.

Comment: I will try online availability option, physical media storages are obsolete, even USB sticks.

Comment: If you want it to fit well in the printed copies, you can buy SD cards :-)

Answer (score 5):

While publishing data sets on *arXiv* might be a decent option, I suggest you to consider posting your research results and artifacts to [figshare](http://figshare.com) or [Zenodo](http://zenodo.org). Both services allow artifacts to be not only *citable*, but also *discoverable* (via DOI assignment). *Version control* is supported as well, but the advantage of Zenodo in this regard in comparison with figshare is Git and GitHub integration.

Comment: It sounds like there is already a DOI available, since the asker has said that they have published a paper with these data. Is it necessary to upload somewhere else too? Is figshare or Zenodo more likely to stick around than the journal?

Comment: @MJeffryes: The beauty of the repositories that I recommended is that both allow to create _citable artifacts_, which, in this case, would refer to **citable data sets** (with _separate DOIs_). This is a very popular trend today in the light of overall bigger trend of wider promotion and use of the _reproducible research_ paradigm. As for the longevity, I am pretty confident in both services, especially _Zenodo_. IMHO it will stick around, at least, as long as a typical journal, if not longer, since it is EU-funded and backed by more than solid CERN IT infrastructure.

Comment: It sounds like Zenodo is the perfect solution for this problem. I will certainly bookmark it for possible future use...

Comment: @Floris: You are welcome. I am glad to be able to help.